# How to add more item in a list view without refreshing the previous item

Tags: android

I have a listview in which i am adding some data after fixed interval.but I don't want to set the adapter again as it will refresh the complete list.Is there any method to add item without refreshing the complete list.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use the following (in `RecycleView` not `ListView`):

```
notifyItemInserted(0);//NOT notifyDataChanged()
recyclerViewSource.scrollToPosition(0);
//Scroll up, to use this you'll need an instance of the adapter's RecycleView
```

Answer (score -1):

You can call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` to just update the list.

Adapter's `getView()` is called at different times and there is no particular pattern. So your views are updated whenever `ListView` wants it to be updated.

But as far as I see it, you are looking for `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged`. The workflow should be something like this.

```
Set adapter to ListView
Add data to adapter`
Call notifyDataSetChanged() on adapter.
```

It will at least prevent your list to bounce back to first item on the list. 
Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
adapter.add(<new data item>); // to add data to your adapter
adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();  // to refresh
```

For eg.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

public void onCreate() {
   ....
   ....

   ArryList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
   for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
     data.add("Item " + (i+1));
   }

   adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
   setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Now whenever you have new data to be added to list you can do following

```
private void appendToList(ArrayList<String> newData) {
    for(String data : newData)
        adapter.add(data);

    adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
}
```

Comment: It is refreshing whole list.

Answer (score -1):

you can use this .[notifyDataSetChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged())

However notifyDataSetChanged() only works For an ArrayAdapter,if you use the add, insert, remove, and clear functions on the Adapter.